# how to add a textchanged event to a textbox in the code-behind

Tags: asp.net, textbox

i created a text-box through the code behind but was unable to add a text-changed event to it
here is what i

```
 protected void insert(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}

protected void update(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.TextChanged += "insert";

    e.Cell.Controls.Add(tb);

}
```

i tried this but it didn't work for me.
what is the problem, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to bind a handler to an event in code-behind, what you actually do is to write the name of the handler itself, not a string

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
    }

    protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

To make a little more clear, imagine that C# has a list called `EventHandler`, and every time the text changes on the text box (blur event in client side), C# executes all the methods inside that list. Now, how do you add a method to that list? You use `+=` operator. Now, if you want to add two handlers, you can write:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged2);
    }

    protected void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This method is the first in the list. So gets executed first.
    }

    protected void textBox_TextChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This method is the second in the list.
    }
```

Comment: It is not working for me. my question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293861/how-to-fire-textboxchanged-event-on-dynamically-added-textbox-in-gridview

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a delegate (the *method* itself) instead of a string (the method's *name*):

```
protected void update(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.TextChanged += insert;

    e.Cell.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```