# How to fire textboxchanged event on dynamically added textbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, I can add n number of textbox in gridview dynamically. My problem is, I want to fire textboxchanged event, if user change the text of any textbox in any row of gridview.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    Width="907px" style="text-align: center" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"> 
</asp:GridView>
```

**ADDING COLUMNS IN GRIDVIEW:**

```
 foreach (string a in crcl)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select qty from purchaseinstruction where project ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND circle = '" + a + "' AND item = 'BIFURCATION' AND material = '" + mat + "'", agr);
                SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr1.Read())
                {
                    string val = dr1[0].ToString();
                    if (val.Length > 0)
                    {
                        row[a] = val;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[a] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row[a] = 0;
                }
                dr1.Dispose();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

ADDING TEXTBOX ON ROWBOUND:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 3;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        crcl = (List<string>)ViewState["bdi2"];
        foreach(string a in crcl)
        {
            TextBox TextBox101 = new TextBox();
            TextBox101.ID=a;
            TextBox101.Width = 60;
            TextBox101.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[a].ToString();
            TextBox101.AutoPostBack = true;                
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(TextBox101);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have three problems
 1. After postback textboxs get dispose
 2. How to retain the value of textboxes for textboxchange?
 3. How to know which textbox fire textboxchange